# Initial value issue in Auto complete() flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

I am working with AutoComplrte() widget in flutter, but I am facing issue with initial value property.

I am calling the api and then set the value to the initial value but at first ui is build so initialValue is set as null, please help me to solve this.

I try with setState but not working, as initialValue can not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `AutoComplete` usage, with the initial value. As soon as the widget is built, the initial value `"ora"` is shown. When you click on it, it only shows the option orange, as expected:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  final List<String> items = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "orange"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Autocomplete<String>(
            optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) => items.where(
              (element) => element.contains(textEditingValue.text),
            ),
            initialValue: const TextEditingValue(text: "ora"),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```